# How to write a complex where clause in Android SQlite Database

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I am new to Android programming. And facing so many challenges write the below query for android SQlite

```
select * from train_South where instr(substr(stations,instr(stations,'ABC')),'XYZ') >1 and instr(stations,'ABC') >0
```

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: use `db.rawQuery(mySQLQuery);`

Comment: what is the problem with the query? didn't get your question

Comment: Thanks @Funkystein.. But instr function is not working..